# Make multiple checks for HTTP POST responses in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I have a page from where a customer can make multiple payments.Each payment is made thru  https to an external source which at the end sends an HTTP POST response.The response is sent after the user has finished the Payment process.

I searched everywhere and I found many methods which tackle the problem with curl, php://input, but I can't figure out how to make multiple checks.With curl I tried this approach:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It didn't worked; I didn't used

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

as the postfields are sent to the server initially via a hidden form which is automatically submited via JQuery.

I would like to know how could I make multiple checks in order to see if the user has finished the Payment process.

Comment: You should be getting a callback from the service provider, no?

Comment: You should look into the official API for your client payment system. If however you insist making your own from scratch you can do this with a [`for`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) statement

Comment: Yep, I should get an HTTP request!

Answer (score 0):

If you are making several calls at once, I would suggest setting up some type of queue.  For instance, when you submit the form, it actually sends the information to a script which queues the payments to be processed.  Then, you can poll the queue using AJAX and show a progress meter or other UI effect while the queue is being processed.  Once it's complete, and the queue is empty, the page reflects that the payments are all successful, as well as display any errors reported.

Having a queue system would also solve the problem of the state not being saved between requests, and would continue to process, even if the user closed the browser before it was complete.

Comment: I though at this but could be possible?When I  submit the form the info is sent to the Bank's own system so I can't make any request on the state of the payment only after it is completed.

Comment: that's my point.  Don't submit it directly to the bank from the form.  Send it to a queue and use a cron job to send the payments to the bank.   You can use something like ZMQ or Pheanstalk, or you can write something fairly simple yourself to do this.